# How to use conditional formatting to progressively turn green to red as the distance between two dates increases

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

Cell B3 contains a date, under "Email Delivery Date". Cell C3 Contains a date as well. What is the formula or formulas that i am supposed to use in order to have those cells turn from green to yellow to red the further they get apart?

Ex. 1 day between the dates would be green, 3 days between the dates would be more yellow and anything past 7 days would be red.

If someone could help me I would appreciate it!!

I tried conditionally formatting the dates expecting for it to color code both columns but instead it just made them red to green dependent on if the date was closer or further from todays date, and not based on the distance between the dates.

Comment: Could you give details on what you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

In a 3-color scale definition for the cell `C3` you should choose **formulas**:
Minimum: `=$B$3 + 1` (green)
Midpoint: `=$B$3 + 4` (yellow)
Maximum: `=$B$3 + 7` (red)
Unfortunately you must use absolute addresses, therefore this format definition cannot be copied. When you need to copy it, you must prepare suitable macro in VBA.